# How can find and sure hard disk of the server is SSD?

Tags: ssd

How can find and sure hard disk of the server is SSD?

Linux and Windows, I woulk like to know both.

Comment: I suggest having a look at this. Your first step should be improve your question http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault

Comment: Physically inspect the server.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux you can find out the harddisk specifications by installing lshw (and call it with "lshw -class disk"), or with dmidecode, but the first is easier. On Windows I don't know.